# VPN stopped working after installing software updates

Tags: networking, updates, vpn, update-manager

My VPN stopped working 2 days ago after installing Ubuntu software updates.
I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS I was prompted to install updates and did so on Sept 24 or 25, 2020.

Since letting the updtes automatically install I cannot connect to a VPN.
I have Surfshark. I enter ...

```
sudo surfshark-vpn
```

I get ...

```
Checking for connection status...
Not connected to Surfshark VPN
Was unable to connect to VPN server. Please try another server.
```

I also have Protonmail VPN. When I start is with ...

```
sudo protonvpn connect
```

I get ...

```
Connecting to JP-FREE#2 via UDP...
[!] There was an error connecting to the ProtonVPN API.
[!] Please make sure your connection is working properly!
```

I have another Ubuntu computer on the same home network. It is running 18.04 LTS. I have no such issues with that laptop.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

I cannot answer why exactly is it not working anymore, I had the same issue though.

What I did to fix it:

```
sudo surfshark-vpn forget
sudo surfshark-vpn
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved it yet, but in case anyone else has the same problem, this is how I got it back up.
I got it working by uninstalling network-manager-openvpn, network-manager-openvpn-gnome, and openvpn-systemd-resolved. This also gets rid of OpenVPN and Surfshark itself, so the two packages need to be reinstalled afterwards.
There is some conflict with these packages, apparently.

Comment: This is not an answer. There is no evidence that what help you will help others too. I would recommend to look in systemlog first. Please post output of journalctl here.

Comment: Yeah, I added that to the bug report that Joe did on Launchpad. Thanks for the suggestion!
bug 1899410